# How to reduce space between items in flexbox justify-content: space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a footer for my website and I am using flexbox for layout. This is CSS for my footer:

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

They have a lot of space between them. How do I decrease that space?

If you need any more info, please comment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use flexbox's `justify-content` rule you can control the spaces between menu items

```
.footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

You can also use `justify-content: center` or `justify-content: space-around`

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `justify-content: space-around;` and it will distribute the space at the beginning and the end like this:

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div>content 1</div>
  <div>content 2</div>
  <div>content 3</div>
  <div>content 4</div>
</div>
```

if that does not fit what you want then use a container and set a max width to it and `margin: auto` to center it:

```css
.content-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="content-footer">
    <div>content 1</div>
    <div>content 2</div>
    <div>content 3</div>
    <div>content 4</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```