# Manipulate the spacing between elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was using space between/ space evenly to try and have equal spacing between elements and it works fine. What I am trying to do is reduce the space between them after evenly splitting them. I couldn't find any working solution. I have tried line-height and manipulating the margin but it didn't work. Is it possible to reduce the size after spacing elements evenly? If there isn't what is the proper way to space elements evenly and also control their spacing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I want the items to either float right or left not centered!

Also, this is the only SO link I could find about this: [How to reduce space between items in flexbox justify-content: space-between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396773/how-to-reduce-space-between-items-in-flexbox-justify-content-space-between)

```css
.leftHeaderItems {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  margin: 0px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftHeaderItems">
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <p>Item 3</p>
  <p>Item 4</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
</div>
```

**Update:**
Also, tried gap property as suggested by @mianbato by I can't figure out how to set items in a row, not a column.

```css
.leftHeaderItems {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-row-gap: 3px;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftHeaderItems">
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <p>Item 3</p>
  <p>Item 4</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `space-evenly` means the browser controls this. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: have you tried with `gap` property?

Comment: @connexo space elements evenly and also control their spacing is what need

Comment: That is a contradiction.

Comment: @mianbato Just tried that didn't work take a look at the update above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `space-evenly` that means you want the browser to calculate and apply the distancing for you.

If you want **control** over the space between the items, use `column-gap`.

You can control the horizontal alignment using `align-content` on the container element:

| align-content | result in LTR | result in RTL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| center | centered | centered |
| flex-start | left | right |
| flex-end | right | left |

```css
.leftHeaderItems {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 12px;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftHeaderItems">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 3</p>
    <p>Item 4</p>
    <p>Item 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: question on your code. How can I align the items to the right or left?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `display: grid` and then adjust spacing with `grid-gap` which I have set to `12px`

```css
.leftHeaderItems {
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  background: green;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftHeaderItems">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 3</p>
    <p>Item 4</p>
    <p>Item 5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using display flex and gap property

```css
.leftHeaderItems{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap:1rem;
  height: 7%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  background: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="leftHeaderItems">
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <p>Item 3</p>
  <p>Item 4</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How exactly to improve @connexo

Comment: "*[...] it works fine. What I am trying to do is reduce the space between them after evenly splitting them [...]*" Then run your snippet. My answer is the only of the 5 that does what you are asking. With no word did you say you don't want them centered. You said *it works fine* and *I am trying to reduce the space **between** them*.

Comment: I specifically said something related to space evenly and space evenly never centers the items in div. You can add an edit to my question at where I went wrong @connexo

Comment: I quoted from your question. With no word does your question ask for removing the centering of items or removing the space *before* the first item, you only talk about the space *between them*.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'justify-content: center' and then use 'flex-basis: [some-value]' to adjust to your need;

```
.leftHeaderItems {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-basis: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  margin: 0px;
  background: green;
}

.leftHeaderItems > p {
  flex-basis: 90px;
}
```

Comment: There are values like 'max-content', 'min-content', 'fit-content' to use for 'flex-basis';

Answer (score 0):

if you want to edit margin value of clild elements after you use space between / space evenly to parent element,
margin should be given to the child elements, not the parent element.

```
.leftHeaderItems {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  right: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  background: green;
}
.leftHeaderItems > p {
  margin : auto 10px; 
}
```